# How to get values in jquery from jsp using for loop?

Tags: java, jquery, html, jsp, jstl

In my Jsp the value and class  is generating dynamically in a loop.

```
<div>
    <c:forEach var="interestTab" varStatus="loop" items="${interestParam}">
        <c:set var="interestFields" value="${fn:split(interestTab, '|')}" />
        <c:set var="maxAmt" value="${interestFields[1]}" scope="page" />
        <c:set var="minAmt" value="${interestFields[0]}" scope="page" />
        <c:set var="interestRate" value="${interestFields[2]}" scope="page" />
        <div class="personalcal-${loop.index}" style="display:hidden;">
            <div class="minamount-${loop.index}">
                ${interestFields[0]}
            </div>
            <div class= "maxamount-${loop.index}">
                ${interestFields[1]}
            </div>
            <div class= "intrate-${loop.index}">
                ${interestFields[2]}
            </div>
        </div>
    </c:forEach>

</div>
```

i want to get all the values in jquery how can i do it ?? if it was not dynamically generated class or id then i can get it simply through $(".class").text(). but now my class is changing with loop how can i get it ??

Comment: i didn't get your problem , will you explain more

Comment: In my requirement the i want to get the values ${interestFields[0]} ,${interestFields[1]},${interestFields[2]} in my jquery file. if its class is not dynamically generated then i can get it through this $('.minamount').text(). but now the class is changing everytime then how can i get it ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
put the below line in your jsp
<input type='hidden' value='${fn:length(interestParam)}' id="interestParamCount"/>

here is how to iterate in your js file

  for(counter = 0 ; counter < $('#interestParamCount').val();counter++){
      alert($('.minamount-'+counter).text());
      alert($('minamount-'+counter).text());
      alert($('intrate-'+counter).text());
  }
```